# C# Generic to Session

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oop

I been trying to use generic to store data in session.
It will have 2 page and 1 class name person to process the information.

Page 1 default page would allow user to input name and select gender and date.
I'm trying to store the submitted to generic & session to bring to 2nd page display all submitted user data.

**DefaultPage**

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    Person p;
    List<Person> Test;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Test = new List<Person>();
            Session["carrytonext"] = Test;
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       Person p = new Person(TextBox1.Text, DropDownList1.SelectedValue, Calendar1.SelectedDate);
        Label1.Text = p.PrintPerson();
        Test = (List<Person>)Session["carrytonext"];
        Test.Add(new Person(TextBox1.Text, DropDownList1.SelectedValue, Calendar1.SelectedDate));

    }
}
```

**Here is my class:**

```
public class Person
{
    public string name;
    private string gender;
    private DateTime dob;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {return name;}

        set
        {name = value;}
    }

    public string Gender
    {
        get
        {return gender;}

        set
        {gender = value;}
    }

    public DateTime Dob
    {
        get
        {return dob;}

        set
        {dob = value;}
    }

    public Person(string name, string gender, DateTime dob)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.gender = gender;
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public string PrintPerson()
    {
        string s;
        s = "Hello, my name is " + name + ". I'm " + gender + ". My DOB is " + dob.ToShortDateString() + "\n\n";
        return s;
    }
}
```

**On my 2nd page:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (var inputstring in Test)
    {
        ListBox1.Items.Add(inputstring + "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set session from test list again:

**page 1**

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Person p = new Person(TextBox1.Text, DropDownList1.SelectedValue, Calendar1.SelectedDate);
    Label1.Text = p.PrintPerson();
    Test = (List<Person>)Session["carrytonext"];
    Test.Add(new Person(TextBox1.Text, DropDownList1.SelectedValue, Calendar1.SelectedDate));
    // Add this line to your code
    Session["carrytonext"] = Test;       
}
```

**page 2**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<Person> test = (List<Person>)Session["carrytonext"];  
    foreach (var inputstring in Test)
    {
        // change here
        ListBox1.Items.Add(inputstring.PrintPerson()+" ");
    }
}
```

Comment: every time i check the listbox it always show namespace.Person(< my class), seem the value din't actual pass thru. can you guide me some about this?

Comment: Thank you it works! can you explain a little bit about "PrintPerson" ?